# Set CLion to use .hpp header, rather than .h header when creating a new C++ class?

Tags: clion

Using the context menu, I can easily create a `.cpp` and a header file in CLion by right clicking and `new` > `C++ Class`.

The header file has a `.h` extension. How do I make `.hpp` the default header extension?

Comment: File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> C/C++ -> Tab [New File Extensions] -> Header Extension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click and select `new` > `C++ Class`.

Click the settings icon next to the type drop down box:

[image]

Select the desired header extension:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Settings->Editor->Code Style->C/C++->Tab "New File Extensions"` and then:

[image]